# Gitlab cache chromium-browser installation to be cached for all pipelines

Tags: git, chromium, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a stage where chromium-browser is installed with : 
apt-get -y install chromium-browser

In my next stage I had to install it again.

So every time the pipeline executes it goes over this installation stage. Is there any way this installation can be cached so that a new pipeline job does not have to download the chromium-browser again. And in the same pipeline the next stage also does not have to download it again.

I'm using specific runner.

Comment: You're probably using the docker runner, in that case just prepare an image with everything you need an use that.

Comment: Hi Jakub, Yes that is what i have planned to do. and upgrade the software in every stage before using.